# Use `yarn` with CircleCI 2.0

Tags: circleci, yarnpkg

Yarn doesn’t have docs on a 2.0 installation.
Request for docs

- Here is 1.0 docs https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/yarn/
- Where is 2.0? https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/yarn/

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to find a solution to?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tried to get it working myself Yarn project uses CircleCI themselves. See their Circle configuration file from GitHub: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml

Answer (score -4):

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: node:7.10.0
    working_directory: ~/app
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: yarn
      - run: yarn test
```

Comment: Maybe a few words of explanation what you intend with your question; and how this is an answer would turn this into something that is helpful for other folks as well ...